# Как изменить цвет верхнего сайдбара в sublimetext3?

Tags: sublime-text-3

На данный момент у меня такая тема.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И мне не нравится вот этот момент
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно это изменить поменяв цвет с белого на черный чтобы было так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В винде, вроде, никак...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зайдите в параметры --> цвета, внизу снимите галочки с этих пунктов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как говорится лучше поздно чем никогда ))))